# What is port 49160 in docker-run?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am following this [tutorial](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) to set up `docker` for my node.js rest api and there is this line in the tutorial:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d <your username>/node-web-app
```

And this description:

> The -p flag redirects a public port to a private port inside the
>   container. Run the image you previously built:

From the description, I know that port **49160 is a public port** and **8080 is a private port**. Since I am exposing port 5001 in my nodejs app, so I think I am running:

```
docker run -p 49160:5001 -d <your username>/node-web-app
```

But what exactly is a public port? Why is it "49160"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example port 8080 leads to some server (probably web server / Node) located inside of your Docker container. The outside (the host you're working on) port is `49160`. The Docker setting named `-p` connects the inner port `8080` to the outer port `49160`. If you now open the browser in your host system and hit the url `http://localhost:49160` you will essentially access port `8080` inside the container.

Port `8080` is usually used for web servers. It is not obligatory though.

Port `49160` is just some port you or the auther of the tutorial decided to take as an example.

If you have a server inside the container listening on port `5001` it will not be accessible in your setup. If you want to make it accessible, you could adapt the following command:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -p 49159:5001 -d <your username>/node-web-app
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of port `49160`, it's very clear, however, I have tested the command stated in the question `docker run -p 49160:5001 -d <your username>/node-web-app` and it successfull connected to my server in the container. So I guess I don't need the extra `-p 49160:8080 -p 49159:5001`?

Comment: The process of connecting two ports i.e. `-p 49160:8080` is called binding. You can bind as many ports as you like. It depends on your setup. Just repeat the schema with the `-p` param.

Answer (score 3):

It can be anything. Tutorial just used a random port. You can change it whatever you want. Then you can access your node-web-app running inside container at port 5001 at localhost:49160 from your host machine.

Comment: So am I allowed to chose any number as my public port? What will the public port be used for?

Comment: @Andus Yes, you can take any public port, but you should check the port first on your system to avoid collisions with other programs.

Comment: yes, you can choose any available port. The port is used to connect to container. By default you cannot connect to your node-web-app:5001 from outside the container. Since you have bound the host port 49160 to 5001 using `-p 49160:5001`, you can connect to localhost:5001 from your host machine to connect to the node-web-app.  Please read - https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/